# How to change the cellType from custom to Text in POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, data-formatters

I am trying to parse an excel file which is having some columns which are in Custom format.I have to convert them into Text before parsing.I am trying to implement a condition that if the celltype is blank and custom it will be converted to text format ,
I am trying this code but not working

```
Workbook workbook = excelManager.getWorkbook();     
DataFormat fmt = workbook.createDataFormat();
CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(fmt.getFormat("@"));
```

But I think this @ will not work for all custom cells. Can anyone please help me? I am using `poi 3.16` and version can not be changed.

Comment: Why do you need to change the type before parsing? Why can't you just fetch the cell's value as-is, and reformat it if required post-fetching?

Comment: Yes, before parsing

Comment: @Gagravarr because the  code is failing to parse the custom cells , to i need to change its type before parsing.

Comment: Which code is failing? And failing how? We're not mind-readers here... you're going to have to help us to help you!